# I'm considering dual-booting this on my desktop, but will everything work?

Tags: ati, graphics, java, minecraft, runescape

Ok so right now I have Windows 8 on my gaming desktop that I use constantly. The two games I run most are RuneScape and MineCraft. I am wondering one, will these work on Ubuntu? And two, will my AMD Radeon HD 6850 work with Ubuntu?

I have used it before and didn't like it too much (probably because the laptop I was running was horrible and I didn't [and still don't] know how to install anything through coding or whatever I had to do) but I want to give it another shot.

Comment: This is really three questions in one: Can I play Minecraft on Ubuntu? Can I play Runescape on Ubuntu? Will AMD Radeon HD 6850 work with Ubuntu? (My answers are: yes, yes, don't know.) You should really post three separate question posts.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/how-to-install-runescape-linux-game.html) may help with Runescape. I don't play Runescape, so I can't testify to the accuracy of the article. Minecraft can be played on Ubuntu - a friend of mine and I set it up on his computer. I did a little research and it appears (from what I could see) that, yes, the AMD Radeon HD 6850 should work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, [Minetest](http://minetest.net) may be worth considering.